# In Swift, Failed to send SMS but MFMessageComposeViewController Delegate Show sent

Tags: ios, swift, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

I am using `MFMessageComposeViewController` to send SMS from my app.

The `didFinishWithResult` delegate method of `MFMessageComposeViewController` shows that the message has been sent successfully but actually this SMS failed to send due to insufficient balance. So `MFMessageComposeViewController` does not show me the correct result.

How do I know that the Messages app failed to send an SMS? Is there any way to get the failed status?

Comment: Detecting Changes to the Availability of Messaging To be notified of changes to the messaging capabilities of the current device, add an observer to the MFMessageComposeViewControllerTextMessageAvailabilityDidChange notification. The system delivers that notification to your observer when the status of messaging changes. For more information: https://developer.apple.com/reference/messageui/mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MFMessageComposeViewController/addAttachmentURL:withAlternateFilename:

Comment: Thanks for your concern. Actually, this notification posted when the value returned by the canSendText() class method has changed and canSendText() is check only if the device capable of sending SMS. So, if Messages app failed to send SMS, we don't get that failed status. Exactly, i need the status when Messages app failed to send that SMS which i am sending through MFMessageComposeViewController.

Comment: Why? All of status stuff is there, I mean Apple's documentation. The MessageComposeResult must be responsible for providing these status for you. They're .sent, .cancelled, .failed! The system knows and immediately tells you about it's status. Hope it helps you

Comment: An alternate way to compose SMS messages is to create and open a URL that uses the sms scheme.

Comment: Sending SMS by create and open URL is not suitable for me, because its not allow to send message body.

Comment: Unfortunately your words are right! Good luck. But your problem is so strange for me

Comment: May be, but thing is that MessageComposeResult is showing sent which is actually failed SMS. 
Thank You

Comment: Are you solved your problems?

Comment: Not yet. As @OMK said its not possible to know if SMS send failed by Messages app. Apple restrict all over accessing Messages app, get phone number. So, i should change my way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to know if the message is Sent or Failed from Messages app.

We get a result in `messageComposeViewController:didFinishWithResult:` once a message has been successfully queued for sending.

Comment: If it's not possible to know from Messages app then what can i do for my app. I need the exact status of sending SMS.